# annotated timeline, graph flickers when I redraw

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline

I want to redraw the graph when I zoom in and then when I zoom out but there's a flicker as it redraws. Someone suggested to add a ready eventlistener but doesn't that just run a function after another has returned ready? And drawing the chart returns ready but wouldn't that still cause the graph to flicker? Anyway can someone explain how to do this with sample/pseudo code?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by 'redraw'? The annotated time series chart will render to whatever zoom level you set it to using the slider beneath the chart. Are you reloading data into the chart when that changes (and if so, how come?) and noticing a flicker, or are you noticing the flicker each time the chart changes when the zoom is modified?

Comment: the former. I wanted to change the resolution so if there were too many data points when you zoom out the graph would draw again and have less points which are averages of the original

Answer (score 1):

There's a technique called double buffering which eliminates flickering when redrawing -- basically, you draw everything to a bitmap, and then draw the new bitmap over the old one without erasing anything in between.

The following link describes it pretty well:

http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/DoubleBuffering.html

John

Comment: well. it'd be great if I could do that here.